# Javascript does not execute on Chrome but works fine on FF and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I have javascript code to populate tabs on my page and the script works fine on FF and IE. However the script does not execute on Chrome. I am not exactly sure what is wrong with the code that it won't show up on Chrome browser. Chrome debug inspector is not helping me much to find out the issue.

> For bet type tabs (link attribute is not clickable and text doesn't show up) 
>   HTML

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul id="betTypesTabs"></ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
function drawBetTypesTable(events, eventIndex) {

    // Clean the tabs
    $("#betTypesTabs").html('');

    // The required order: WIN, PLACE, EXACTA, QUINELLA, TRIFECTA, FIRST FOUR, RUNNING DOUBLE
    var orderedBetTypesIds = [1, 2, 105, 107, 106, 111, 108],
        eventId = events[eventIndex].id,
        categoryId = events[eventIndex].categoryId,
        betTypes = events[eventIndex].markets[0].betTypes,
        horseSelections = events[eventIndex].markets[0].selections,
        marketDescription = events[eventIndex].markets[0].marketDescription;

    // If event is the last one, Running Doubles cannot be shown
    if (eventIndex == events.length-1) orderedBetTypesIds.pop();

    $.each(orderedBetTypesIds, function (index, value) {

        var betTypeId = orderedBetTypesIds[index],
            i = null;

        $.each(betTypes, function (betIndex, betTypeValue) {
            if (betTypeValue.id == orderedBetTypesIds[index]) {
                i = betIndex;
                value = betTypeValue;
                return false;
            }
        });

        if (i != null) {

            // Draw the tab
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.className = eventId + "_betTypeId_" + betTypeId;
            a.text = value.name;

            var li = document.createElement('li');
            li.appendChild(a);
            document.getElementById("betTypesTabs").appendChild(li);

            // Draw the div with the table
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.id = eventId + "_betTypeId_" + betTypeId;

            var table = document.createElement('table');
            table.id = eventId + "_betType_" + betTypeId + "_table";
            table.cellspacing = "0";
            table.cellpadding = "0";
            table.width = "100%";
            table.className = "table_racing";

            document.getElementById("tabs").appendChild(div);
            document.getElementById(eventId + "_betTypeId_" + betTypeId).appendChild(table);

            // Bind click action to the tab link
            var currentA = $("ul#betTypesTabs").find('a[class="' + eventId + '_betTypeId_' + betTypeId + '"]');
            currentA.click(function(){

                // Making the tab active
                $("ul#betTypesTabs li").removeClass("active");
                $(this).parent().addClass("active");

                // Showing the correct div
                $("div#tabs div").hide();
                $("#" + eventId + "_betTypeId_" + betTypeId).show();

                // If it is a Running Double, highlight the next race number
                if (betTypeId == 108) {
                    (function(eventIndex){
                        var nextRaceNumber = events[parseInt(eventIndex)+1].raceNumber;
                        $("#raceNumber_" + nextRaceNumber).removeClass("gray");
                        $("#raceNumber_" + nextRaceNumber).addClass("orange");
                    })(eventIndex);
                }
            });

            var tableId = table.id;

            (function(betTypeId, eventId, categoryId, i, tableId, eventIndex) {
                // PLACE or WIN, WIN/PLACE bet types
                if (betTypeId == 1 || betTypeId == 2 || betTypeId == 3) {
                    drawPlaceBetTypeTable(eventId, categoryId, betTypes[i]);
                    drawSelections(betTypeId, tableId, horseSelections);
                }
                // EXACTA, QUINELLA, TRIFECTA, FIRST FOUR bet types
                else if (betTypeId == 105 || betTypeId == 107 || betTypeId == 106 || betTypeId == 111) {
                    drawExactaBetTypeTable(eventId, categoryId, betTypes[i]);
                    drawSelections(betTypeId, tableId, horseSelections);
                    drawHorseSelectionFooter(betTypeId, tableId);
                }
                // RUNNING DOUBLE
                else if (betTypeId == 108) {
                    drawRunningDoubleBetTypeTable(events, eventIndex, betTypes[i], 6);
                }

                // Append NB description if does not exist
                if (marketDescription != null && $("#" + table.id + '_notabene').length == 0) {
                    appendBetTableFooter(table, marketDescription);
                }
            })(betTypeId, eventId, categoryId, i, tableId, eventIndex);
        }
    });

    // Click on the 1st tab
    $("ul#betTypesTabs a")[0].click();
}
```

> For race type (links are clickable but race type text doesn't show up on chrome)
>   HTML

```
<div id="raceNumbers" class="racenumbers">
</div>
```

JS

```
function drawAllRaceNumbers(events) {

    // Clean parent element
    document.getElementById("raceNumbers").innerHTML = '';

    // Draw a category name, which is same for all events
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = events[0].categoryName + ':';
    document.getElementById("raceNumbers").appendChild(p);

    for (var i in events) {
        var a = document.createElement('a'),
            eventNumber = events[i].raceNumber;

        // Racing specials
        if (eventNumber == null) {
            eventNumber = parseInt(i) + 1;
            a.text = eventNumber;
        }
        else a.text = raceAbbr + eventNumber;
        a.id = "raceNumber_" + eventNumber;
        a.className = "gray";
        document.getElementById("raceNumbers").appendChild(a);

        // Binding click event for the race number
        $("#raceNumber_" + eventNumber).unbind();
        (function(i, raceNumber) {
            $("#raceNumber_" + raceNumber).click(function() {
                drawRaceView(events, i);
            });
        })(i, eventNumber);
    }

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = "clear";
    document.getElementById("raceNumbers").appendChild(div);
}
```

Edit: Removing the link to my dev environment.

Comment: Not sure, hard to spot but try instead of: `a.text = eventNumber;` use `$(a).text(eventNumber);`

Comment: Could you specify what the events variable contains and how you create/get that?

Comment: I'd remove the anonymous functions, move them out of the functions and for loops. You could have a problem with this too: `(function(){...}(params...))` instead of `(function(){..})(params..)`.

Comment: @A. Wolff It doesn't work

Comment: @Nish but you have to replace all your `a.text` in your code... I was thinking it was obvious. And btw, if including jQuery, use it. Don't mix up js/jQuery syntax. You can but think about code consistency. EDIT: if still doesn't work, please highlight in your question which line in your code doesn't work as expected. Quite boring to have to check all code to spot it when you should be able to spot it for us

Comment: @A. Wolff It works now, thanks. Mixing up JS and jQuery was the root problem. You can put your solution as an answer and I will vote up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change all your lines which use '.text' to set content of element. This doesn't work on chrome. You could replace it using instead `.innerHTML` or, as you are already using it, use jQuery for that: `$(a).text(data)`

Comment: `.textContent` seems more appropriate (IE9+) than `.innerHTML`

Comment: @Saebekassebil Ya it would but as you pointed it, not supported on IE8

Comment: @A.Wolff Then you can use $(a).html() I guess. jQuery will make sure it works as expected, also in IE8 if you use jQuery 1.x

Comment: @KoalaBear sure you can but as OP is just setting text string, why not using `.text()`?

Comment: Absolutely. That was a reaction on the textContent / innerHTML part

Answer (score 0):

You have error : `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.`

Comment: That's only a warning. And already 'fixed' in jQuery 1.11.

It's not the cause of the problem asked.

Comment: Thanks I am aware of that. But this has nothing to do with the Chrome JS problem.